# composition of an integer number

Tags: combinatorics, integers

Given two positive integers $m$ and $n$. I would like one special non-negative solution to the following system (which is related to a composition of an integer number):
$$\begin{cases} \sum a_i = m \\ \sum (i+1)a_i =n \end{cases}$$

How to describe the solution $(a_0,\dots,a_j)$ with largest index $j$ such that $a_j$ is nonzero?

For instance, if $m=2$ and $n=4$, we have $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,2,0)$ as solutions. So the solution which I want is $(1,0,1)$.

Edit: Another example, for m=3 and n=6 we have $(0,3)$, $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,0,0,1)$, so I take $(2,0,0,1)$.

Comment: I believe your illustration example generalizes to all cases $m,n$ positive.   Start by verifying the case $m=1$, i.e. one summand.

Comment: Since the summands of equal value are "lumped together", the problem might well be more closely related to *partition* rather than composition of an integer (as order of identical summands doesn't matter).

Comment: May I ask where you found this problem?

Comment: If $m=n$ we have $a_0=n $ as the largest nonzero index.

Comment: This problem comes from Representatio Theory of Lie algebras, where these sort of tuples appear as exponents of polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A necessary condition for a solution is that $m \le n$:

$$ m = \sum_{i=0}^j a_i \le \sum_{i=0}^j (i+1)a_i = n $$

If $j$ is the largest index for which $a_j \gt 0$, then either $a_j$ is the only nonzero summand ($m=1$ and $n=j+1$) or else we can remove $j+1$ from $n$ and reduce $m$ by $1$ to obtain the smaller problem for $m'=m-1$ and $n'=n-j-1$.

The smaller problem has a solution only if $m' \le n'$:

$$ m-1 \le n-j-1 $$

$$ j \le n - m $$

Thus **the largest possible nonzero index** is $j = n-m$.

To see that such a solution exists, it suffices to verify the cases $m=1$ (when $n=j+1$ and $a_j = 1$) and $m=n$ (when $a_0 = n$).

**Remarks:**  The proof actually shows that maximum index $j=n-m$ is obtained by a summation in only one way.  In the case $m=n$ the inequality at top forces $a_0=n$ to be the only feasible summation, with $j=0$.  In the case $m=1$ there can be only one summand, and it must be $a_j=1$ with $j=n-1$.  All other cases start by setting $a_j=1$ with $j=n-m$, after which the reduced case $m'=m-1$ and $n'=n-j-1$ satisfies the case $m'=n'$.  Thus the reduced case has only one feasible summation.

The summations studied here are partitions of $n$ into exactly $m$ parts:

$$ \underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{a_0\text{ times}}+\underbrace{2+\ldots+2}_{a_1\text{ times}}+\ldots+\underbrace{(j+1)+\ldots+(j+1)}_{a_j\text{ times}} = n $$

where $\sum_{i=0}^j a_i = m$ is the collected number of parts (summands).

The original question can thus be recast as, "What is the *largest possible part* of a partition of $n$ into exactly $m$ parts?"  In this context our answer may be expressed as either $m = n$ and the largest part is $1$ or $m \lt n$ and the largest part is $n-m+1$.

However I think the OP has raised a different question in the Comment below, namely what is the:

**Largest possible value of $a_{n-m}$**

When $m \gt n$, no solutions of any kind are possible (since the $m$ terms would add up to something more than $n$).

In the case $m = n$, there is exactly one solution, where each of the $m$ terms is one (since if any term were more, the total would exceed $m=n$).  Stated differently, $n-m = 0$ and $a_{n-m} = a_0 = n$ is the unique solution.

Finally, if $m \lt n$, there may be multiple solutions, but only one where $a_{n-m} \gt 0$.

This is clear if we remove a single term $n-m+1$ from the summation and put $m' = m-1$ and $n' =  n-(n-m+1) = m-1$.

As just observed the reduced problem has a unique solution where $n' = m'$ is expressed as $a_0 = m'$ ones.  Putting this together with the single term $n-m+1$ we removed, we get:

$$ a_{n-m} = 1 \;  , \; a_0 = m-1 $$

and this is the unique solution where $a_{n-m} \gt 0$.

A more interesing problem arises if we do not require $j=n-m$ to be the index of the leading term.  When $m \lt n$, there may solutions whose leading term's multiplicity $a_j$ is greater than one.  Therefore we may ask in these cases how to determine the largest leading term's multiplicity $a_j$.

For example, if $n=16$ and $m=6$ the possible partitions include:

$$ 11 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 16 $$

$$ 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 16 $$

$$ 4 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 16 $$

$$ 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 16 $$

So how does one find the partition where such $a_j$ is largest? Here we [say with Scheherazade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheherazade) that an answer to this more interesting problem must await a new post.

Comment: Your answer gave me everything I needed when I asked my question. However, you said "... The question asked is, what is the largest possible part of such a partition?" and I really want to know it too. Is there a way to determine the largest value to $a_{n-m}$? Actually, by considering these solutions as $(n-m)-$uples, "what is the biggest $(n-m)-$uple (solution) to this problem with respect to the reverse lexicographic order on these $(n-m)$-uples"?

Comment: @Stam:  I clarified (hopefully) my remark about partitions of $n$ with exactly $m$ parts, and the connection to $a_{n-m}$ being nonzero with $n-m+1$ being the largest part (summand) of such a partition.  There is no flexibility in choosing a nonzero $a_{n-m} \gt 0$, but perhaps the rest of my edit poses a question of interest to you and others.

Comment: Your answer was fantastic: it helped me and gave an extra bonus! I would appreciate more details for the last part which you mentioned (related).