# composition of an integer number into some limited parts

Tags: combinatorics

Given $k,m,n\in\mathbb N$, $n\ge m$, is there a way to find the "leading solution" with respect to the reverse lexicographic order for the following problem?
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_i = m   \\ \sum_{i=0}^{k} (i+1) a_i = n \end{array}\right.$$
By the leading solution with respect to the reverse lexicographic order I mean the solution $(a_1,\dots,a_k)\in (\mathbb N\cup \{0\})^k$ that is the largest tuple which respect to this order in a point-wise comparation.

Remark: Due to a previous que [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252203/composition-of-an-integer-number), it is possible to determine the largest index $j$ such that $a_j\ne 0$.
So, the question here remains for $k<  n-m$.

Comment: See [this previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252203/composition-of-an-integer-number) by the same user for related analysis.

Comment: I know the previous question is linked, but you might want to add more to this question explicitly, as it takes a while digging around the other question to find the relevant results. In particular, it would be nice to add to this question the finding that $k \leq n - m$ is a necessary condition, and perhaps some examples & intuitions would be nice too.

Comment: Edit to above: $k \leq m - n$, for some reason notation was changed from last question (aaaargh!)

Comment: @ColmBhandal I just changed the notation as you observed: keeping the notation of the previous question. I also wrote something about the bound for $k$, since it is a first reduction step.

Comment: @hardmath I did not know how to cite another question. I just did it as you remarked. However, the question remains valid.

Comment: I agree with Colm that the current Question would be improved by adding some of your thoughts, such as an example that illustrates what your "reverse lexicographic order" amounts to for an example where there are multiple possible solutions.  If you wish, use the example I mentioned at the end of my answer to the earlier Question, $n=16$ and $m=8$.

Comment: @hardmath I will insert some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I am attempting to answer this with a "greedy" approach. I may be wrong in my logic, so please correct me if I am. At a high level, my approach is to first maximise lexicographically for the sum to $n$ and then "nudge" this sum into shape so that the sum to $m$ is satisfied. For this, let's define $S_n = \sum_{i=0}^{k} (i+1) a_i$ and $S_m = \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_i$. We want both $S_n = n$ and $S_m = m$ for some $a = (a_0, a_1, \dots, a_k)$, which is maximised according to reverse lexicographical ordering.

**Step 1:** We want the maximum $a$ for $S_n = n$. Construct $a$ easily as follows. Take $a_k = \lfloor \frac{n}{k + 1} \rfloor$. Then let $r$ be the remainder of the division and find the largest $j$ such that the followoing is non-zero: $a_j = \lfloor \frac{r}{j + 1} \rfloor$. Then take the remainder from that, and so on, until you are left with remainder $0$ or you end up "dumping" all the remainder in $a_0$. Now $S_n = n$ but it may be that $S_m < m$.

**Step 2:** If the above step left us with $S_m < m$, then we need to modify $a$ by making it smaller, so that $S_m = m$, such that our modification preserves $S_n = n$. Call the new vector $a'= (a_0', a_1', \dots, a_k')$. We still want the maximum such $a'$, so naturally we want to pick the lowest $i$ such that we must decrease $a_i$. To find this, again proceed greedily as follows. Set $a_1' := 0$ and $a_0' := a_0 + 2a_1$. This increases $S_m$ by $a_1$ and preserves $S_n$. Continue by setting $a_2' := 0$ and $a_0' := a_0' + 3a_2$ etc. until eventually $S_m \geq m$. If $S_m > m$, we've gone too far, and we simply "correct" our last step, which I'll sketch in the next step.

**Step 3:** Suppose in the process of step 2 we end up with $S_m > m$. Then there is some $a_i$ such that $i \times a_i$ pushed the sum over the edge. So in this case, we correct by first incrementing $a_i'$ and decrementing $a_0$ until just before $S_m \leq m$ again. Then we do the same for $a_{i - 1}'$, $a_{i - 2}'$ etc. until $S_m = m$. This phase is a bit fuzzy but I believe it will work, it just needs the details worked out a bit better.

Of course, we may get lucky and never have to do steps 2 and 3. I realise that this is an algorithm rather than a mathematical answer, and furthermore I have not *proved* that my constructed vector is indeed lexicographically maximal. But I believe this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: The previous Question settles the case $k = n-m$, with the limited options that $n=m$ and $a_0=m$ necessarily, or that $n \gt m$ and $a_{n-m} = 1$.  Taking $k \lt n-m$ to be the largest nonzero *index* in the summation, I'm curious about which choice of $k$ maximizes $a_k$.  Your formulation suggests that to maximize $a_k$ we want the leading index $k$ as small as possible.

Comment: Made massive edits to the question there. Was completely neglecting the sum to $m$. Yes I believe to maximize $a_k$ you can just do it greedily, but it's yet another variation on the question that's asked, so maybe another post is necessary for that one (with appropriate links)!

Comment: Your answer is quite interesting. I have not thought/seen about this procedure. It is not helping me because I thought that it would be an "exact" form as in the case cited by hardmath. Anyway, I appreciate your attention.

Comment: Hi @Stam, unfortunately that's the best my brain has been capable of producing for the moment. Perhaps coding the algorithm above and testing on a few cases for small $n$ would be a good step to help solidify our confidence in the optimality of this solution. However I do not have time right now to write this code, unfortunately.